# How can I mask an SVG's background using polygons?

Tags: svg

I'm trying yo make an SVG with a gradient backgound color from red to yellow to green, inside the SVG I've got 2 polygons (for now because there'll be more) that I wish would mask the SVG's background. I tried the following code:

```
<svg height="500" width="500">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(34,177,76);stop-opacity:1" />
    <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,242,0);stop-opacity:1" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(237,28,36);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <polygon points="0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100" fill="url(#grad1)">
    <polygon points="100, 100, 150, 250, 300, 350, 150, 400, 100, 300" fill="url(#grad1)" >
    </svg>
```

How can I apply a background to the SVG and have the polygons show the part of the background based on their position?

[image]

**UPDATE**

I updated my code (YES it needs some work) to achive a path with a unified background and also have transparent polygons in case you wish to add a onclick event.

```
<?php
//Array with the different sections and their coordinates
        $body['item1'] = array(array(0, 0), array(100, 0), array(100, 100), array(0, 100));
        $body['item2'] = array(array(100, 100), array(150, 250), array(300, 350), array(150, 300), array(100, 300));
        $body['item3'] = array(array(300, 50), array(300, 350), array(200, 350), array(200, 50));
        ?>
        <svg x="0px" y="0px" height="500px" width="500px">
        <defs>
        <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
        <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(34,177,76);" />
        <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,242,0);" />
        <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(237,28,36);" />
        </linearGradient>
        </defs>

        <g id="singlePath_correctGradient" fill="url(#gradient)">
        <?php
        $polygon = '';
        echo '<path d="';
        foreach ($body as $key => $values) {
            $polygon .= '<polygon points="';
            $a = 1;

            foreach ($values as $coord) {
                echo $a == 1 ? ' M ' . $coord[0] . ', ' . $coord[1] : '';
                echo $a == 2 ? ' L ' . $coord[0] . ', ' . $coord[1] : '';
                echo $a > 2 ? ', ' . $coord[0] . ', ' . $coord[1] : '';

                $polygon .= ($a == 1 ? '' : ', ') . $coord[0] . ', ' . $coord[1];
                $a++;
            }
            $polygon .= '" onclick="alert(\'' . $key . '\')" fill-opacity="0"/>';
        }
        echo '"></path>';

        echo $polygon;
        ?>
        </g>
        </svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I now show two snippets below. The first (original) snippet shows a manual solution. The second (newer) snippet shows a programmatic solution using JavaScript.

Are you OK with converting your polygons into paths? If so, you can combine multiple polygons into a single path and then apply the gradient to the whole thing. In the first code snippet below, I show three groups:

1. your original two polygons...incorrect gradients
2. the two polygons converted to two paths...still incorrect gradients
3. the two paths merged into a single path...correct gradient

Basically, to convert a polygon to a path, change the `points` attribute to a `d` attribute. Then, within the `d` value string, place an `M` (for "MoveTo") at the beginning and an `L` (for "LineTo") after the first two numbers. Putting an `M` halfway through the path is your way of telling the program "lift the pen and, without drawing anything, move it to this new location and continue drawing there", effectively allowing you to draw multiple "shapes" within a single path.

```html
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(34,177,76);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,242,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(237,28,36);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g id="twoPolygons_incorrectGradient" fill="url(#grad1)" transform="scale(0.5) translate(0,0)">
    <polygon points="0, 0 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100"></polygon>
    <polygon points="100, 100 150, 250, 300, 350, 150, 400, 100, 300"></polygon>
  </g>
  <g id="twoPaths_incorrectGradient" fill="url(#grad1)" transform="scale(0.5) translate(300,0)">
    <path d="M 0, 0 L 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100"></path>
    <path d="M 100, 100 L 150, 250, 300, 350, 150, 400, 100, 300"></path>
  </g>
  <g id="singlePath_correctGradient" fill="url(#grad1)" transform="scale(0.5) translate(600,0)">
    <path d="M 0, 0 L 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100 
             M 100, 100 L 150, 250, 300, 350, 150, 400, 100, 300"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <text   x="0" y="70">wrong</text>
    <text x="150" y="70">wrong</text>
    <text x="300" y="70">right</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I've done the conversions above manually. However, this type of conversion could also be done programmatically, e.g. with JavaScript, which I have done in the second snippet below. Essentially this does the following:

- get all desired polygons
- for each polygon, read the `points` attribute value string
- duplicate the final point (to numerically close each shape...important for strokes/borders)
- insert the "M" (MoveTo) and "L" (LineTo) as described above
- concatenate all theses strings
- add a final "Z" (ClosePath) to close the path
- create a new single path element
- place the concatenated string from above into the `d` attribute of the path
- apply the gradient to the new path

The example below initially shows 7 polygons with the same gradient applied to each individual shape. Note that the last polygon is simply one point and is thus invisible, indicated by the dotted circle.

After clicking the "Combine..." button, polygons 2 and 3 are combined into a single path, as are polygons 4 and 5 as well as polygons 6 and 7. The same gradient as before is now applied to each combined path. Note how the path combinations affect the placement of the colors along the gradient.

Note that the utility function I've written makes it as simple as adding more polygon id's to an array in order to combine more than two polygons together.

```js
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

var combine = function(polygonIds, newPathId) {
  var $newPath = $(document.createElementNS(xmlns, "path"));
  // jQuery does not work here, e.g. var $newPath = $("<path>", {id: newPathId});
  $newPath.attr("id", newPathId);
  $("svg").append($newPath);
  var dStr = "";
  polygonIds.forEach(function(polygonId, idx, arr) {
    var $polygon = $("#" + polygonId);
    var ptsStr = $polygon.attr("points");
    dStr += "M " + ptsStr.replace(/, *| +/g, " ").trim().replace(/^([^ ]+ [^ ]+ )(.*)/, "$1L $2 $1");
  });
  dStr += "Z";
  $newPath.attr("d", dStr);
};

$("button#combine").click(function() {
  combine(["shape2", "shape3"], "path2and3");
  combine(["shape4", "shape5"], "path4and5");
  combine(["shape6", "shape7"], "path6and7");
  $("#path2and3").attr("fill", "url(#grad1)");
  $("#path4and5").attr("fill", "url(#grad1)");
  $("#path6and7").attr("fill", "url(#grad1)");
  $("#labels").remove().appendTo($("svg"));
});
$("button#delete").click(function() {
  $("path").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Best viewed on "Full Page"</p>
<p>The "Combine..." button will combine polygons 2 and 3, polygons 4 and 5, and polygons 6 and 7. Polygon 7 is a single dot and is thus essentially invisible. The same gradient is applied to each individual polygon as well as to each of the new paths.</p>
<div>
  <button id="combine">Combine polygons into paths</button>
  <button id="delete" >Delete new paths           </button>
</div>
<svg height="500" width="500">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%"   style="stop-color:rgb(34,177,76);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="50%"  style="stop-color:rgb(255,242,0);stop-opacity:1" />
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(237,28,36);stop-opacity:1" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g fill="url(#grad1)" transform="scale(1) translate(0,0)">
    <polygon id="shape1" points=" 30, 100   60, 160   30, 220    0, 160"></polygon>
    <polygon id="shape2" points="100,   0  120,   0  110, 120"          ></polygon>
    <polygon id="shape3" points="130, 100  160, 160  130, 220  100, 160"></polygon>
    <polygon id="shape4" points="230, 100  260, 160  230, 220  200, 160"></polygon>
    <polygon id="shape5" points="210, 200  220, 320  200, 320"          ></polygon>
    <polygon id="shape6" points="330, 100  360, 160  330, 220  300, 160"></polygon>
    <polygon id="shape7" points="330, 320"                              ></polygon>
  </g>
  <circle cx="330" cy="320" r="10" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-dasharray="3 3"></circle>
  <g id="labels" font-family="Verdana" font-size="18">
    <text x=" 24" y="165">1</text>
    <text x="104" y=" 20">2</text>
    <text x="124" y="165">3</text>
    <text x="224" y="165">4</text>
    <text x="204" y="310">5</text>
    <text x="324" y="165">6</text>
    <text x="324" y="305">7</text>
  </g>
  
</svg>
```

Comment: I used the first snippet, I made tests with Michael Mullany's answer and your two answers. Merging multiple paths into a single path was the solution for my requierement but all answers are valid. Like you said it all depends on what the person needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your gradientUnits to "userSpaceOnUse" - that way the gradient is defined in the SVG box space, not the filled unit. Easy. (and please, close your elements!! - SVG is XML)

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" height="500px" width="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="0" x2="300" y2="350" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0" style="stop-color:rgb(34,177,76);" />
    <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,242,0);" />
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(237,28,36);" />
    </linearGradient>
    </defs>

    <polygon points="0, 0, 100, 0, 100, 100, 0, 100" fill="url(#grad1)"/>
    <polygon points="100, 100, 150, 250, 300, 350, 150, 400, 100, 300" fill="url(#grad1)" />
    </svg>
```

Comment: I like this solution, and I learned something new about svg. Thanks. However, I just want to point out one difference between this solution and the answer I posted. This answer allows the gradient to be applied over the whole svg box (if I understand correctly). My solution allows it to be just applied to those "two shapes" (now just one shape really). The area of the svg box and the area of the two shapes might coincide, but they might not. (Note where the red is in all examples.) Thus, which solution you choose really depends on where exactly you want the gradient applied.

Comment: My update to my answer shows how application of a gradient to a path made from multiple polygons can produce effects impossible with a gradient applied to an entire svg box. Specifically the gradients can be morely finely controlled in terms of placement. This still does not negate the power of the solution explained in this current answer. It does, however, highlight an important difference.

Comment: That's not quite right Andrew. The x1/x2/y1/y2 in the gradient element controls the dimensions of the gradient in the unit system of the SVG box - if you want the gradient applied to just the shapes, then you can change those dimensions to match the bounding box of the union of your polygons. The OP doesn't quite specify, but I assumed he wanted a gradient defined on the whole box - but that's not required by my solution. I updated the dimensions to match that exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, Michael. Yes, one could adjust the x1/x2/y1/y2 gradient values in order to potentially achieve a desired effect on, say, two polygons that you wished to "group". However, if that gradient already also existed on other separate shapes, this change would affect them all, which might not be desired. Part of this comes down to a trade-off: Your solution would require changing the gradient but leave the shapes unchanged. My solution would require changing the shapes but leave the gradient unchanged. Again, depends on what you want.

Comment: By the way, Michael, when I say that, with your solution, something is "impossible", I'm not referring to finely placing a gradient, full stop. I'm referring to finely placing a gradient, but on only some shapes. Your solution obviously can also allow gradient placement as finely as mine. It's just that your solution is more global, mine more local.